# Making an "infinite activity" like PlayStore or LINE app

Tags: android, memory, android-activity

My question title may be kinda weird, but what I meant can be seen on PlayStore or LINE messenger app, for example:

- PlayStore:

  1. Open an app detail page
  2. Tap another app from the recommended apps, which opens another app detail page
  3. Repeat
- LINE:

  1. Open a sticker detail page
  2. Tap on another sticker from the recommendations, which opens another sticker detail page
  3. Repeat

What is the best practice to implement those kind of behaviour?

I have tried making a single instance Activity that updated its data and views, and modified its back press behaviour to display the previous item instead of just finishing. It works, but is there a better and simpler way?

Comment: I think the best practice is using fragments, and replacing the active one with the one the user clicks. But that's my opinion. Waiting to see if someone with more experience can suggest us ;)

Comment: I thought about using fragments too, but haven't gotten to try to implement that yet.
The thing is, PlayStore and LINE looks like they used Activities, because of the enter/exit animation. It boggles my mind that they can open so much pages without ever getting crashed on my devices.

Comment: Well, assume that they are kinda some of the best programmers on android and they probably do like one month of test only work before any release. Said that, fragment enter/exit animation can be customized, so probably that's it. Honestly using activities would be really heavy for our phones, fragments are way lighter